# How can I check which route was used to call the page/component?

Tags: routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

Given a Razor page/component used in Blazor Server Side with

```
@page "/items/create"         // create route
@page "/items/edit/{id:long}" // edit route
```

In my code I need to know if the `create route` or `edit route` was used. How can I check this?

I am already aware of `NavigationManager.Uri` but that's not really error proof, e.g. `NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("edit")` will also evaluate to true for `http://localhost:123/items/create/?edit=faked_edit` (so will claim that the `edit route` was used, though the `create route` was used).

Answer (score 4):

I had to do something similar in my case and couldn't find a proper solution but the workaround to check the whole path worked for me. You can use the below example:

`NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("/items/edit/")`

Additionally, in one place I also checked if the `id` is not null or empty which will then be the edit page.

Comment: I would steer on the `id` being set. `0` or `null` indicates create.

Comment: for me it seems strange that `/edit/0` is then actually add. I ended up creating a component, see my answer below. However I agree that in reality checking for `id == 0` should be also fine,

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a component `MyEditor` which includes the add and edit functionality.

```
// Edit.razor
<MyEditor EditMode="true" />

// Add.razor
<MyEditor EditMode="false" />
```

Then inside `MyEditor`I use the `EditMode` parameter instead of trying to figure out if it's add or edit via the `NavigationManager`.

Comment: I still don't figured out how you determine if the component should have the property EditMode setted as "true" or "false"

Comment: @Ewerton Depends on the razor page on which you include it. Don't confuse routing with calling a component in a razor page!